# share session info with laravel and back

Tags: php, laravel

Our web site is built on top of a custom php mvc framework and we wanted to slowly convert each flow (for eg: signups) to Laravel.

So in essence, the existing code and the new code using laravel have to co-exist. But we hit a snag, where session information set by laravel is not availble to the other mvc and vice-versa because of their conventions.

For eg, the custom mvc uses the following.

```
$_SESSION['AUTH']='TRUE';
```

While Laravel uses something like this.

```
Session::put('AUTH', 'TRUE');
```

We tried to set $_SESSION['AUTH'] = 'TRUE' through laravel classes. But we are not able to access it when control is passed to the older MVC.

I know its complicated, and i should just wait to convert the entire code base to Laravel, and be done with it. But we are a small company with minimal resources. So we dont have the luxury to stop feature development and spend time re-writing using Laravel Exclusively.

So my question is this. How , if by any mechanism, can we achieve this?

Global variables?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this problem? I'm  stuck on the same problem as well. I would love hear which approach do you follow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posted it below. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you have the following folder stuctures

projectFolder/oldMVC

projectFolder/Laravel

in the oldMvC/main.php we included the following

```
require '../Laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
require_once '../Laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

After that we were able to access session and other config variables set in Laravel from the non Laravel MVC.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use Laravel's `Auth`-Class here, listen to the `auth.login` event and set your session flag by hand.

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    $_SESSION['AUTH']='TRUE';
});
```

It is the easiest way and you only have to delete the event listener when you completly migrated to Laravel.

I know this is a quick and dirty thing, but after full migration you don't want to use the `$_SESSION` ever again to manage your authentication ;) so I think this should be a very good bridge between your new and old codebase.

Comment: Hi @Jan P. how can i use your code to integrate a cakePHP 2.5 and Laravel 5.1 ? can you provide more details? or steps? suposing cakephp will be migrated to laravel and a user can log in from cakephp and reach a laravel app.

Answer (score 1):

Actually only by requiring `bootstrap/autoload.php` and `bootstrap/start.php` you will not be able to access the real Laravel session. Not even by calling `Application::boot()` anymore.

I've created a Gist, that makes it possible to share Laravel's session and check authentication from external projects:

https://gist.github.com/frzsombor/ddd0e11f93885060ef35

Comment: Please, how can i use this gist to integrate a cakePHP 2.5 app to Laravel 5.1 ? where your code will be placed ?